# Node.js array.sort with custom method causes RangeError: Max Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: node.js, sorting, coffeescript

So, I have an array of 100,000+ items, and this line causes it to blow the call stack:

```
@sortedList.sort (a, b) ->
  return if a.value > b.value then -1 else 1
```

I'm about to go implement a custom sort of some variety (suggestions, anyone?) to work around the issue, but I just wanted to make sure that I'm not doing something blatantly stupid that's causing it to blow up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if `a.value == b.value`? A [`sort` comparison function should return zero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) if the items are the same:

> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to a lower index than `b`.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`.

So you want something more like this:

```
if a.value > b.value
  -1
else if a.value < b.value
   1
else
   0
```

The missing `a.value == b.value` branch could cause `sort` to lose its mind and make a mess all over the place; no `==` branch is saying that *`a` goes before `b`* and *`b` goes before `a`*, you can't expect a sensible result from that.

Comment: Hey, that fixed it. I was previously using a much smaller data set and it just must not have had any == in it. Thanks!